# Deploy Google App Engine app for Google Earth Engine

Tags: python, google-maps-api, google-earth-engine

Basically, an app from Google App Engine makes a request to Earth Engine (server to server basis) then renders this image to a web page.

In my case, it requested SRTM data:

```
    mapid = ee.Image('USGS/SRTMGL1_003').clip(bound).getMapId({'min': 0, 'max': 1000})
```

I was able to replicate demo described in [Google EE demo apps](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/app_engine_examples) in my localhost and online as well: https://service00-201702.appspot.com/

However, as you see the DEM is in black and white and without legend.
Do you know where to config its color ramp and legend which shows elevation range with color ?

This is github link for this app: [github.com/google/earthengine-api](https://github.com/google/earthengine-api/tree/master/demos/server-auth)